# How to keep variable `$post` to using in another file

Tags: plugins, functions, database, views

I create a plugin to quick payment.

When user click button Quick pay. It show popup call `views/display-popup.php`.

In this file, I declare variable `$post`.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $name = get_the_title();
?>
```

Ok, it will get `$id` and `$name` values and show.

On `function.php`, I call it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_share', 'fun_add_link_below', 50 );
function fun_add_link_below()
{
    global $post;
    if(absint($post->ID) > 0){
        require(ROOTDIR . '/views/display-popup.php');
    }
}
```

Problem is:

I create a new file have name `ajax-send-email-save-database.php`.

This file also needs using `$post` variable to update my database.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_cart_send_mail','ajax_cart_send_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_cart_send_mail','ajax_cart_send_mail'); 
function ajax_cart_send_mail(){
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $name = get_the_title();
}
?>
```

But I receive values of `$id` and `$name` is null.

Update:

My js ajax file:

```
$('input#submit-order-quick_view').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = '';
    var data_details = {
        'action': 'ajax_cart_send_mail',
        'hoten': getdata(frm,'hoten'),
        'sdt': getdata(frm,'sdt'),
        'email': getdata(frm,'email'),
        'diachinhan': getdata(frm,'diachinhan'),
        'product_title' : product_title,
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: product_ajax.url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: data_details,
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("Error");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$post` isn't set in an admin-ajax.php request because you're not querying for any post or inside a loop. In your script that sends the ajax request you'll need to send the post ID and retrieve a post object in the callback:

```
function ajax_cart_send_mail(){
    $post = get_post( $_POST['post_id'] );

    $id = $post->ID;
    $name = $post->post_title;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_cart_send_mail','ajax_cart_send_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_cart_send_mail','ajax_cart_send_mail');
```

Comment: I tried with `$post = get_post( $_POST['post_id'] );` or `$post = get_post( $_POST['id'] );`. But when I `var_dump($post)`. Variable `$post` still null.

Comment: You need to send the post id in the ajax request, you can't pull it out of the ether.

Comment: I'm the newbie in Wordpress. Can you add more code? I updated my Ajax file. So sorry about that, I have the problem at this too long times.